# Trouble creating Datastax Studio connection

Tags: graph, datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Datastudio version: 1.0.0 or 1.0.1

When you try to create a new connection to a valid host, you get:

> TEST FAILED Unable to connect to DSE gremlin analytics server at
>   127.0.0.1:8182. It is likely that the server is not listening for connections on 127.0.0.1. To mitigate this issue: Make sure this
>   server is running DSE graph (has a 'graph' workload). Try setting the
>   rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 in dse.yaml.

It seems like it is always trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 Gremlin server. I could not find any configuration whithin Datastudio that addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit connections from the connection browser page.  Click on the hamburger menu in the on the top left, select connections, then edit the connection in question.  Heres a couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is that even though you specify another host for the connection, it still looks for 127.0.0.1. That is what I meant in the posted example.

Comment: There might be something wrong with your DSE(DataStax Enterprise) configuration.  Here are a couple other things to try if you haven’t yet already:

-  Set the **rpc_address** in in DSE_HOME/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml to **0.0.0.0**
-  Ensure when you start DSE that the you have started it with the graph workload enabled.  Example:  **DSE_HOME/bin/dse cassandra -g**, where **-g** enables graph.

If you are still having trouble feel free to send us a note at studio-feedback@datastax.com and we can help troubleshoot further.